# PHP выдаёт не отформатированный вывод, как исправить?

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Столкнулся с такой проблемой что при выводе массива или объекта браузер выдаёт не отформатированную строку, и по итогу вместо того чтобы получить то что на этом скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я получаю вот такого формата вывод где приходится тщательно разыскивать каждый элемент:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема меня преследует еще с начала изучения PHP, но теперь когда начал переходить к реальным проектам - данная проблема крайне сильно мешает жить, буду крайне благодарен если сможете помочь).

IDE: PHPStorm
Браузер: Google Chrome, EDGE
Версия PHP: 8.1

Comment: Ну так воспользуйтесь тегом `<pre></pre>`

Comment: Покажи код. Но вообще да, юзать `pre`

Comment: либо в хтмл выводите в `<pre>` либо смотрите исходный код страницы. Вообще это несоклько олдскульно, конечно, но быстро. А так современны фреймворки имеют отладочные панели, куда  много полезного выводится, а IDE - отладчики

Comment: в первом скриншоте возможно контент тайп отдается как текст а не хтмл, или еще чего нить.

Comment: Да, спасибо <pre> помогает, однако видел в обучающих материалах все корректно отображается и без них, из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Из-за чего угодно. Надо смотреть сам материал и код. Может там он смотрел через исходный код страницы, а может через спец функцию, которую сам написал

Answer (score 0):

Вывод данных в браузере зависит от заголовка ответа сервера
`Content-Type`, который сообщает браузеру какого типа данные передаются, например text/plain или text/html, [тут больше примеров](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

По умолчанию, данные выводимые PHP-скриптами, веб-сервер считает HTML-кодом и отправляет их с соответствующим заголовком `Content-Type: text/html`, поэтому браузер трактует эти данные как HTML, т.е. игнорируются повторяющиеся пробельные символы и переносы строк.

Решить проблему можно несколькими способами:

- использовать тег [pre](http://htmlbook.ru/html/pre), который сохраняет исходную разметку текста
- устанавливать заголовок `header("Content-Type: text/plain");`, который сообщит браузеру, что это простой текст, а не HTML-код. Но это не поможет, если заголовки уже были отправлены https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.headers-sent.php
- использовать специализированный инструмент, например [Xdebug](https://habr.com/ru/post/328094/)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так будет красиво показать

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';
```